# Assigning Groups based on Preference List (Take 3)

Tags: algorithm

This is the third iteration of a question that had started from a purely algorithmic point of view, and has now turned in to a desperate mission to find a code sample that I can understand.

What I am trying to do is create *g* groups of a list of people, attempting to satisfy as many preferences as possible. Each person has given an unranked list of top *n* other people in the list that they would like to be assigned with. It (my program) needs to consider mutual requests as more influential that one-way, and should (hopefully) find something close to the optimal solution.

I want some sort of a code sample (in, really, any C-based language or detailed pseudo-code) so that I can understand the required algorithms and write my program. After my first question, I have determined that this will probably require some sort of variant on the Stable Marriage Problem, but I have been unable to find a full example in either pseudo-code or an actual language that I can understand.

I have asked previous questions about the algorithm [HERE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14486/assigning-groups-based-on-preference-list-take-2?noredirect=1) and [HERE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8534/assigning-groups-based-on-preference-list/8536?noredirect=1), but have not come up with anything (I think it's due to the extremely low number of users on those SE forums). Now I am asking a question here, on the hope that the much higher view rate coupled with a programming oriented question will get me an answer.

Yes, I do realize that questions like this have been asked before, but none are both applicable and answered.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

To add more detail (in response to comments):
I have a list of people. For each person, I have a list of their top preferences of other people that only includes other people in the main list. No lists are sorted in any way. A name on a preference list means that the requester would like to be with the requested person. I am looking for a way to create a specified number of groups, each containing only people that I have on my main list. I want the groupings to incorporate the preference lists. It should try to put people in the same group if they both request each other in their lists. It should also incorporate requests where one person(person A, in this example) requests someone else (person B), but B does not request A. In this case, although it should still count the request, it should be counted as a lower priority to incorporate than a mutual request.

EDIT:
Again, as per request, here is a JS function that will (hopefully) help explain my goal:

```
/*
Scores a possible grouping
group would be an object, where the keys are names and the values are arrays of preferences. Ex:

    {
        "Person 1": ["Person 2"],
        "Person 2": ["Person 1"],
        "Person 3": ["Person 4"],
        "Person 4": ["Person 2"]
    }

*/
function getGroupScore(group) {
    var totalPoints = 0;

    //Add a point for each request
    for (var person in group) {
        for (var request in group[person]) {
            if(request != undefined && request.length > 0)
                totalPoints++;
        }
    }

    //Add two points for each two-way request
    for (var person in group) {
        for (var request in group[person]) {
            if (group[person][request] != undefined //String validation
                && group[person][request].length > 0 //More string validation
                && group[group[person][request]] != undefined //Array validation
                && group[group[person][request]].indexOf(person) != -1) //Check mutual request
                    totalPoints += 2;
        }
    }

    return totalPoints;
}

/*
Compares two possble groupings
*/
function compareGroups(groupA, groupB) {
    var scoreA = getGroupScore(groupA),
        scoreB = getGroupScore(groupB);

    if (scoreA > scoreB)
        return 1;
    else if (scoreA == ScoreB)
        return 0;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: You have *no idea* how you would approach this? What makes you think we'll do your homework for you?

Comment: Suspiciously similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/18965363/56778

Comment: No, this is not homework, it's part of a personal project. I have tried to come up with an answer myself but all of my solutions would involve initially selecting a person for a seed for each group, which I found often separates people with many requests. I have already seen the question that you linked to after days of searching, but it doesn't have an answer, so it doesn't help me.

Comment: Your question needs a lot of clarification.  I suggest writing a (detailed) function that inputs a set of preferences, and a group, and outputs how satisfied they are so that we can all try to figure out what you are trying to say.

Comment: Then you are also going to have to define what a maximum is.  Is it the the maximum of the sum from each group?  Is it the maximizing the minimum satisfaction?  Then you are probably going to have to post your attempt at reasoning through this problem.

Comment: I have added much more detail, written with the simplest words that I can think of. @DanielV, what do you mean by 'maximum'? I don't see it used anywhere in my posts.

Comment: "as many preferences as possible" is a maximization problem.  You have to understand that there are ambiguities in your request that commenters here can't resolve for you.  All I can suggest to you is, write a function that, if given 2 possible solutions, tells us exactly which solution is better.  Doing so will probably help you solve the problem on your own anyway.  Btw I am also a major wasabi fan.  Good luck.

Comment: Although I don't see the ambiguity in my question, I am the OP and don't have much of a grasp on what I am not communicating well. I have added two JavaScript functions that will score and compare possible groupings, with the hope of explaining my problem.

Comment: @DanielV,  Were you commenting to help add detail or did you have an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: When you use the word group, do you actually mean "partition of a set of people"?  How can you rate a grouping and against a set of preferences when your function only inputs 1 variable instead of 2?  I am pretty good at solving or classifying algorithmic problems when the question is asked clearly, but I don't like guessing at meanings.  I am trying to help.

Comment: Or does group mean pairing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I've been thinking on your problem, and I think I can give you some direction, although I can't quite solve it.

First I'm going to try to rephrase your question a little, correct me if I'm wrong.

Let there be a set of P people, and a table of preferences such as:

```
Preferences of 4 people named A B C D:
   A B C D
 +---------+
A| X   X   |
B|       X |
C|     X X |
D|   X     |
 +---------+
```

In this example, 'A' prefers 'C', 'B' prefers 'D', etc.  Whether a diagonal prefers himself or not will become inconsequential.

Now your problem is to partition the P people into G distinct sets of size N, assuming P=G*N.  For N=2 example:

```
  A C B D
 +-------|
A|x x|   |
C|  x|  x|
 +---+----
B|   |  x|
D|   |x  |
 +---+---+
Here the partition is {A, C} and {B, D}
```

The degree to which a partitioning is satisfied is the sum of the number of X in the diagonal blocks, which in the above example is 3+2=5.

AFAIK, the problem most similar to what you are trying to solve is to construct a Block Diagonal Matrix, or as close to one as possible.  In your case, values outside the diagonal blocks do not count against you.

If you brute force the problem, then you have P!/N! partitions to check.  For small values of P and large values of N, this might be worth implementing directly, although doing it in JS will hurt.  If your solution has to be the optimal result, then you might have to resort to something like this.

If you can allow for "pretty good" solutions, then a randomized approach will probably get close.  Just do greedy rearrangements until no rearrangement helps any longer, and repeat the process several times.

I've also found [this thread](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5486/rearrange-an-ordinary-matrix-to-block-diagonal-form) on another forum which might help you.  Most of the problems related to this assume that a solution where every preference is satisfied exists, and that comes down to a breadth first search.  Obviously if that was true then the result would be your optimal solution, but since it isn't true in general you will probably have to do some heavy studying to modify the known algorithms.

Best Wishes~

Comment: So, you're basically suggesting that I randomly test groups until there isn't much improvement? That's definitely something that I can figure out how to implement.

Comment: Is this the problem you were trying to solve?  Yes, if "good enough" is "good enough", then multiple greedy testing runs from randomly generated starting points is probably easiest.

Comment: After looking through your post and thinking for a while, I have come up with an algorithm that seems to work. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @WasabiFan would you care to share the algorithm with us?